# Differece between two arrow function return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In react arrow function return body is wrapped with parenthesis

```
  this.setState((state)=>({
    count:state.count+1
  }))
```

but in the normal function, we wrapped return body with curly brases

```
   this.setState((state)=>{
    count:state.count+1
  })
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the two return body of function

Comment: See the linked question's answers. The first one returns an object, which `setState` will use to update state. The second one doesn't specify a return value, so effectively returns `undefined`, and so will be ignored by `setState`. (In the second one, `count:` is a label, not the first part of a property initializer.)

Comment: First of all two functions are not equal. Second one has logic error, it has no return argument. It should be written as `this.setState((state)=>{
    return { count:state.count+1 };
  })`. Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body". In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.

Answer (score 0):

The second notation is the classic notation to declare an arroz function with a body. By the way, the snippet has to be modified as it won't work as it is. Here is the working equivalent:

```
this.setState((state)=>{
  return {
    count:state.count+1
  }
})
```

An object is created and returned by the function.

The first notation is used for convenience when the value you want to return is straight forward to compute.

```
this.setState((state)=>({ count:state.count+1 }))
```

The parentheses around the returned object are necessary to indicate that the following curly bracies define an object instead of the body of the function.